# return LINQ Query result in IList and read it another class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, collections

I am using ASP.NET mvc 5. I have one class that holds all the LINQ which can access to another class. now i convert the LINQ query to list variable Query and returning as IList... the i create object of this class--> call the method and get result.

now i can see in debugging object names but i can't see in foreach loop. my list hold mix data types, plus result is merging from different tables...

```
  public IList GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(int FeeSchemeID) 
    {

        using (var db = new QualificationContext())
        {
           var Query = from a in db.FeeScheme
                        join b in db.FeeZoneSchema.Where(c => c.FeeSchemeID == 1) on a.FeeSchemeID equals b.FeeSchemeID
                        join c in db.FeeZone on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
                        select new
                        {
                            FeeScheme = a.FeeSchemeID,
                            FeeZone = b.FeeZoneID,
                            FeeZone_Description = c.FeeZoneDescription
                        };

           return Query.ToList();             
        }   
    }
```

### in controller class...

```
 foreach(var item in obj1.GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(1))
        {
           item.???? (can't access the object here....

        }
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`IList` is non-generic interface, it contains only non-generic `IEnumerable` definition, which enumerates objects. So type of `item` will be `object`. That's why you can see only members of `System.Object` class.

You should either cast `item` to appropriate type or use generic collection parametrized with appropriate type. But you can't use neither of these approaches while you are using anonymous objects, because you don't know anonymous type name. So, you need to create some class which you will be able to cast to:

```
foreach(Foo item in obj1.GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(1))
```

Or use as parameter of method return type:

```
public IList<Foo> GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(int FeeSchemeID)
```

One more option is usage of `dynamic` type, which will resolve operations on object at runtime. You still will not be able to use IntelliSense but your code will work:

```
foreach(dynamic item in obj1.GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(1))
{
     // use item.FeeScheme
}
```

Comment: i have data coming from two mapping classes (for two tables) i.e. do i really need third table to map for just this query???

Comment: @toxic if you don't want to create separate class to hold this data, you can use dynamic type

Answer (score 2):

You should return Generic `IList` of concrete (not anonymous class):

```
public IList<FeeSchemeModel> GetAllFeeZonesForFeeSchemeByID(int FeeSchemeID) 
{

    using (var db = new QualificationContext())
    {
       var Query = from a in db.FeeScheme
                    join b in db.FeeZoneSchema.Where(c => c.FeeSchemeID == 1) on a.FeeSchemeID equals b.FeeSchemeID
                    join c in db.FeeZone on b.FeeZoneID equals c.FeeZoneID
                    select new FeeSchemeModel
                    {
                        FeeScheme = a.FeeSchemeID,
                        FeeZone = b.FeeZoneID,
                        FeeZone_Description = c.FeeZoneDescription
                    };

       return Query.ToList();             
    }   
}

public class FeeSchemeModel
{
    public int FeeScheme{get;set;}
    public int FeeZone{get;set;}
    public string FeeZone_Description{get;set;}
};
```

But I recommend to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>` and use `ToArray()` method instead of `ToList()` method if you don't use special features of `List<T>` (such as method Add())

Comment: i have data coming from two mapping classes (for two tables) i.e. do i really need third table to map for just this query???

Comment: You should not have table. Only type. Or you can inline your method in method with foreach. Anonimous types is visible only in method where it is defined. In other methods it is objects.